# JS: Remove script from other frame with source on other domain

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to remove script from site in frame
from other domain?

Comment: Is it a script intended to prevent you from framing it?

Answer (score 4):

No.  The some-origin policy means that code in your page can't access the DOM of the page within the frame if it's from another domain.

If the page within the frame is a page that you control (i.e. both domains are yours) you could, I guess, set that page up so that if a certain querystring were added to the URL, the script would be removed on the server-side.  But I'm guessing it's not a page you control.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use a proxy to load the content from the other domain and re-serve it from your own (with script removed). I presume you're talking about content that you don't control. (Keep in mind that this may or may not be ethical, depending on the content licensing.)

Answer (score -1):

[There is in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534622.aspx):

```
<iframe security="restricted" />
```

But it's generally considered a broken security mechanism and you certainly can't rely on it.